# Refresh listview adapter on GSM notification receive

Tags: java, android, listview

Say `listview.java` is a file that creates adapter and assigns it to a listview.

What I want is when I receive a GSM notification I want to refresh that listview adapter. So as soon as I receive notification my listview should contain new data.

I am using `onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data)` this method of `GcmListenerService`.

Can I call some method of listview.java from  class **MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {}**  that will refresh the adapter and assign to listview?

If user is already on listview layout then I want it to get updated with new data.

**Any Idea folks how to do it?**

**More clarity**

in listview.java I create an adapter using data from shared prefs. 
when I receive GSM notification I do some changes to shared prefs. Now I want My adapter should be recreated from with new shared prefs and should be assigned to list view.

**Now folks?**

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data)` you can try doing `listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. From the [docs of notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Comment: After I recieve notification I do changes to some values in shared prefs. These shared prefes are used to generate adapter.   

If I set listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() inside onMessageRecieved()   will my adapter be regenerated from values in shared prefs and assigned to listview?

Comment: First of all finish your task with shared preferences and once you are ready to set data on the adapter , then only call notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: but after calling call notifyDataSetChanged() how new adapter will be created from shared prefs automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcast receiver in service on method onRecieve like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
  // You can also include some extra data.
  intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And in activity you will will have to implement changes like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ...

  // Register to receive messages.
  // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
  // with actions named "custom-event-name".
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
}

// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
// with an action named "custom-event-name" is broadcasted.
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get extra data included in the Intent
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);

//here refresh your listview
// adater.notifyDatasetChanged();

  }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

and on receive method refresh your adapter using adater.notifydatasetchanged

Answer (score 0):

Use BroadcatReceiver for refresh listview while receiving Push Notification.

In your activity of ListView add below code,

**ListView Activity**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        -------

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(1001);           
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                handlePushNewMessage, filter);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver handlePushNewMessage = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
            // Update list here and refresh listview using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();          

        }
    };



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(handlePushNewMessage);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

In **MyGcmListenerService.java** add below code on **onMessageReceived()**

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(1001).putExtra("MESSAGE", message);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: in my code MyGCMListner.java dont have onHandleIntent method, Do I need to override like     @override protected void onHandleIntent(){ that two lines}

Comment: Can you explain the solution you provided a bit please? I am a noob, It will help me learning fast.

Comment: Post your MyGcmListenerService class

Comment: In MyGcmListenerService.java add below code on onMessageReceived()

Comment: @Ritzor, did you got the solution?